# Import orders / invoices from old installation

Tags: import, invoice

Due to an very old magento installation we moved our new client over to a complete new magento installation. this because the old one was full of hacks and such.

We still have a backup of course. but he asked us to import all financial order/invoice data so he can do comparisons of he's revenue. 
is there a good way or best practice to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The only good way is to import the whole database - in my opinion. If that's not possible and there are already orders in the new database, I don't see a good option to import the data.

Answer (score 0):

If he's concerned only with looking at revenue for business analytics, it doesn't sound logical to merge the old and new Magento stores together just for this simple task. Why don't you just set up a "locked down" version of his old site so he can export data from there and compare with the new site?

Magento tools for such a purpose are not very robust and he can be better served using data exported from the old site and imported into more powerful analytics software.